# How to find the path of an installed "git" package

Tags: git

I'm trying to get the `google-api-php-client.git api` working on a Godaddy account.

I've "PuTTY'ed" in and run `git clone https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.git`.

Now, I think I need to add the path to my php.ini file.
I have NO IDEA what the path is supposed to be.

- How do i determine the path of a recently cloned git package using the shell?
- What would the correct path to include be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless specified the dir that git clones to is the dir in which you run the git clone command on.

so if I was cloning something into /opt for instance I would cd to /opt and run git clone  which would clone the gits dir into a folder under /opt.

Answer (score 2):

Git should by default clone into a new subdirectory of the current directory from which you ran the `git clone` command.  So, there should be a new directory in your current directory called `google-api-php-client`.  Update your `PHP.ini` file with the path to the Google PHP client and you should be good to go:

```
include_path = ".:/usr/local/lib/php:./google-api-php-client/src"
```

Here `./.google-api-php-client/src` means start at the current directory (where you did the clone), and go into the subdirectory called `google-api-php-client`.

[Here is a link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/installation) to the installation notes for the Google API PHP Git package.